# is below events are enough to check if user is idle on a website using laptop and tablet

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface

is below events are enough to check if user is idle on website. (accessing website using laptop, tablet and automation testing script)

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:onmousemove', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:mousedown', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window:mousewheel', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window.ontouchstart', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window.onclick', ['$event'])
@HostListener('window.onscroll', ['$event'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The events listed in the question are not enough to check if a user is idle on a website. These events only track user activity related to mouse, keyboard, touch, and scroll events. However, a user may still be idle on a website even if they are not interacting with it through these events. For example, a user may be reading a long article or watching a video without any interaction with the website.

There are also libraries available for detecting user inactivity in Angular, such as **ng-idle**
. These libraries provide a more robust and configurable solution for detecting user inactivity on a website.